# ReactJS: Importing Data from External File Throws 'export Data not found' Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, file, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on a ReactJS project and trying to import data from an external file, but I keep encountering an error: `export 'Data' (imported as 'Data') was not found in './data' (possible exports: default)`.

I have a file named `data.js` where I'm exporting an array of objects containing some data. Here's how it looks:

```
// data.js

const data = [
    // Array of objects
];

export default data;
```

In my component file, I'm importing this data using:

```
import React from 'react';
import Data from './data';

const MyComponent = () => {
    // Component logic
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I've double-checked the file paths, and they seem correct. However, I'm still getting this error. What could be causing this issue? How can I resolve it?

**What I Tried:**
I attempted to import data from an external file named data.js into my React component file. Following standard practices, I used the import statement to bring in the exported data object from `data.js`.

**Expected Outcome:**
I expected the import statement to successfully fetch the exported data object named Data from `data.js`, enabling me to use it within my React component.

**Actual Result:**
Instead of the expected outcome, I received an error message stating `export 'Data' (imported as 'Data') was not found in './data'`. This was unexpected and confusing, as I had correctly exported the data object as default in `data.js`.

Comment: What you have will work if your bundler supports imports without file extensions. (If it doesn't, you need to add the `.js`, but I'd expect a different error.) The error message almost looks like it's not for the code you've shown, though. Are you sure your code is really `import Data from './data';`, as it is in the question, and not `import { Data } from './data';`? Because the error almost seems to be suggesting you're trying to import a named export called `Data` whereas in what you've shown you're correctly importing the default export, and so shouldn't be getting an error.

Comment: You have this tagged with FileNotFound exception but your tooling is finding the file, it's complaining that it can't find that specific export in the module. Since it's saying that default is available that suggests that you are provably compiling to commonjs and the tools are converting your default export to an export named default.

Comment: What bundler are you using? What tool or runtime is giving you the error?

Comment: You are trying to import Data (capital D) but you are exporting data (lowercase d) . can you try to import data (lowercase) . and see if it helps?